# Interchanging Workouts

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding, strength-training, shoulders

My current workout routine is as follows:

```
Monday : Chest
Tuesday : Triceps
Wednesday : Lat's/Back
Thursday : Biceps
Friday : Shoulder
```

Saturday, whole day I go to play cricket and Sunday is rest day.

While doing Chest workout, I feel more pressure on shoulders as most of the chest workouts involve Shoulder movement (Chest workout comes after Shoulder in my routine).

So, I am thinking to interchange Lats/Back workout with Shoulder which seems fine.

Please let me know your thoughts about it.

Comment: Depending on how advanced you are, your split might be suboptimal to begin with. For a 5-day-split you'd have to be very advanced, as you're only working each muscle group once a week. If you want to use a 5-day-split though, you can definitely switch stuff around, to accomodate your specific needs. Routines are seldom created for _one_ specific person, so a bit of customization is almost always necessary. For a more detailed answer on how to shift your workouts best, one would have to know all of your exercises for each muscle group with weight, rep and set count, though.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla  Its been more than 1.5 years I am following d same routine. Other than this shoulder issue, I am very much happy with my routine. If I interchange Back with shoulder, it should not b a problem as Biceps don’t need much Shoulder involvement as I am planning to work them out after shoulder.

Comment: If it works for you, go with it! Still, depending on the exercises you do, switching Back with Shoulders might introduce new problems. If you're doing Overhead Press for shoulders, for example, your performance might suffer because you did Triceps only the day before. Also Biceps before Back is not great if you're doing heavy Pullups for Back-day. And so on...

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I never had much sore in Triceps after workout so its not a problem for me to do Shoulder after it but I need to consider ur point `Biceps before Back is not great if you're doing heavy Pullups for Back-day` becoz I hit biceps quite hard and feel sore in muscle even for more than 2 days. Anyway, let me analyse more about it. Thanks for ur valuable suggestions.

Comment: Just noticed those comments are probably long enough to give an answer. ha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, most routines are not created for one person specifically, so they won't address that person's specific needs, prior injuries, disbalances etc. So some adjustments will most likely have to be made by each individual person to suit their needs.

In your case, your shoulder takes probably more time to regenerate than the creator of your routine anticipated. Switching your back-day with your shoulder-day might very well solve that problem, giving your shoulder more time before it is used again. It might also introduce new problems, though, as split-programming is a very complex issue.

Depending on the exercises you do, you might introduce other problems, since most exercises use more than one muscle group. Some examples:

- If you're doing the Overhead Press for shoulders, your performance may go down as your triceps might still be sore from the day before.
- Putting back-day after biceps-day might also impede your performance on heavy Pull-Ups, should you do those.

The above are just two examples for your specific case. Depending on your individual genetics and your regeneration of certain muscles, you might not even experience those. Make sure to check your performance on all your exercises to make sure you're not overlooking anything, and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you do your back and shoulder after biceps and triceps.The reason you are feeling pressure on your shoulders because your upper front part of the body is already tired.
Try this
Monday : Chest
Tuesday : Biceps
Wednesday : Tricep
Thursday : Back
Friday : Shoulder